# Why can't I set a background-color for my navbar?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navbar, nav

I've been trying to set a background color for my navbar and somehow my code isn't working.
Here's the HTML & CSS used:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I also tried adding background-color property to a nav selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What cause you problem is the `float:right` property that prevent your `ul` from having a width

You could use `display: flex`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```